Equivalent of `ifdef` / `#pragma once` in shell `/bin.sh` scripts?
My attempt, atop every one of my—dozens of—shell scripts:
#!/bin/sh

# shellcheck disable=SC2236
if [ ! -z "${BASH_VERSION+x}" ]; then
  # shellcheck disable=SC3028 disable=SC3054
  this_file="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
  # shellcheck disable=SC3040
  set -o pipefail
elif [ ! -z "${ZSH_VERSION+x}" ]; then
  # shellcheck disable=SC2296
  this_file="${(%):-%x}"
  # shellcheck disable=SC3040
  set -o pipefail
else
  this_file="${0}"
fi
set -feu

guard='H_'"$(printf '%s' "${this_file}" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/_/g')"
if test "${guard}" ; then return ; fi
export "${guard}"=1

DIR=$(CDPATH='' cd -- "$(dirname -- "${this_file}")" && pwd)
export DIR

SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR="${SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR:-$(d="$(CDPATH='' cd -- "$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$( dirname -- "${DIR}" )" )" )")"; if [ -d "$d" ]; then echo "$d"; else echo './'"$d"; fi)}"
export SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR

# shellcheck disable=SC1091
. "${SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR}"'/_lib/_common/os_info.sh'

echo 'doing stuff in '"${this_file}"

Unfortunately it always determines the shell scripts as being already-included (so they exit early without executing the script content even-once).
What's the correct way of writing POSIX portable include guards for my shell scripts?

Related:

How best to include other scripts?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425757
How do I source_once in bash?


What should I use instead of BASH_SOURCE on /bin/sh? - Just added this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79318678 but it doesn't answer the other question

You say you want "POSIX portable" but afaik, realpath and bash are both non-standard

it always determines the shell scripts as being already-included : Given that you know about set -..ef.., (hey, where did that go (-;! ), temporarily use set -vx to see a) what will be executed (-v) and b) what the "final" code (for each line) is executed (-x) (which shows results after all cmd-substitutions and variable subs). The -x line is has + prepended. Dbl-quoted strings may be resolved to single quoted strings. Good luck.

Which is to say, set -vx is one of the few debugging tools built into the shell. You should be able to see the execution path and what values are set for variables that is causing the script to always take the "already included" path. Also export PS4='$LINENO >' can be helpful. (you want to use single-quotes here). AND it was a good idea to drop the other options on your set -o pipefail.That could get the "we hate set -e" people in a tizzy. You may also want to read about the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle of coding. Good luck again!

And finally, I can't guess why 3 high rep members voted-to-close but didn't  leave a comment about how you could improve your question. I see 2 issues (not life threatening (-; ) . 1 ) This should be boiled down to the basic problem. The classic reference is [mcve] , which you may find abstract and academic. I prefer the section How to turn a bad script into a good question . 2) Including links to external sites to help define your problem is frowned upon, AND in your case, violations the "Minimal Reproducible Problem Description" from 1) .

In terms of DRY I only repeated one line in the current example. And unfortunately it's currently lots of lines to make it possible to reference the shell script without cding to any particular directory. And I can't use my_get_filepath and my_header_guard functions because of the chicken-and-egg problem. So I'm left with an identical ~17 lines at the beginning of each script
